# Renewal of South African driver's license while living in Italy

Tags: driving-license

My SA driver's license has expired a while ago and I now that I reside in Italy I would like to apply for its renewal. I called the SA consulate in Rome, and it has advised me to look up the requirements online but their website doesn't seem to indicate them.

Could you please advise me regarding this issue?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Searching "renew South Africa drivers license" yielded many results.
[This one](http://www.sahc.org.au/drivers-license.htm) was from the South Africa High Commission, which seems to act in a consular capacity for the South Africa government. This site (from the SAHC in Australia) contains this text:

***Renewal of Driving Licence Card for applicants who reside outside the borders of the Republic of South Africa:***
Applicants should note that a Driving Licence Card cannot be renewed without the applicant applying in person as new fingerprints, photographs, signature and an eye test needs to be submitted.

Comment: High Commissions are analogous to embassies, the practice having arisen during the days of empire and persisting because most Commonwealth countries share the same head of state. The idea of Australia sending an ambassador to represent its queen to the queen of the UK is indeed a bit odd.  I'm not sure why commonwealth republics such as South Africa continue in this tradition; [Wikipedia explains it away with the phrase "for historical reasons."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_commissioner_(Commonwealth)#Current_practice)  So high commissions, like embassies, act in a consular capacity.

Comment: The Department of International Relations and Cooperation (DIRCO) has just replied to my email regarding the query above and has confirmed the impossibility of renewing the license while abroad because the presence of the applicant is necessary for the biometrics to be taken.